# class Rectangle - Python

Tags: python, class, object

I'm just beginning working with object-oriented programming. I have created some classes and am trying to complete the rectangle class. Any and all help is appreciated.

I'm confused about when you need to refer to self and when you can just create variables. For example, in defining the length of the rectangle, I don't know if I should call the variable self.length or just length, and I haven't been able to find any rectangle classes defined in this way.

```
import math

class Point (object):
  # constructor 
  def __init__ (self, x = 0, y = 0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  # get distance
  def dist (self, other):
    return math.hypot (self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

  # get a string representation of a Point object
  def __str__ (self):
    return '(' + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ")"

  # test for equality
  def __eq__ (self, other):
    tol = 1.0e-16
    return ((abs (self.x - other.x) < tol) and (abs(self.y - other.y) < tol))

class Circle (object):
  # constructor
  def __init__ (self, radius = 1, x = 0, y = 0):
    self.radius = radius
    self.center = Point (x, y)

  # compute cirumference
  def circumference (self):
    return 2.0 * math.pi * self.radius

  # compute area
  def area (self):
    return math.pi * self.radius * self.radius

  # determine if point is strictly inside circle
  def point_inside (self, p):
    return (self.center.dist(p) < self.radius)

  # determine if a circle is strictly inside this circle
  def circle_inside (self, c):
    distance = self.center.dist (c.center)
    return (distance + c.radius) < self.radius

  # determine if a circle c intersects this circle (non-zero area of overlap)
  def does_intersect (self, c):

  # string representation of a circle
  def __str__ (self):

  # test for equality of radius
  def __eq__ (self, other):
    tol = 1.0e-16

class Rectangle (object):
  # constructor
  def __init__ (self, ul_x = 0, ul_y = 1, lr_x = 1, lr_y = 0):
    if ((ul_x < lr_x) and (ul_y > lr_y)):
      self.ul = Point (ul_x, ul_y)
      self.lr = Point (lr_x, lr_y)
    else:
      self.ul = Point (0, 1)
      self.lr = Point (1, 0)

  # determine length of Rectangle
  def length (self):

  # determine width of Rectangle
  def width (self):

  # determine the perimeter
  def perimeter (self):

  # determine the area
  def area (self):

  # determine if a point is strictly inside the Rectangle
  def point_inside (self, p)

  # determine if another Rectangle is inside this Rectangle
  def rectangle_inside (self, r):

  # determine if two Rectangles overlap
  def does_intersect (self, other):

  # determine the smallest rectangle that circumscribes a circle
  def rect_circumscribe (self, c):

  # give string representation of a rectangle
  def __str__ (self):

  # determine if two rectangles have the same length and width
  def __eq__ (self, other):
```

Comment: If the variable is just a *temporary placeholder* within a method, you don't need to use ```self```.  If you want the variable name to be an instance attribute, use ```self```.  [Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, setting a value to `self.length` gives you the ability to access this value from other functions inside the class and from outside of the class. If you set a value to `length`, you are able to access this variable only in the current function inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Just a start, try to continue yourself:

```
class Rectangle (object):
  # constructor
  def __init__ (self, ul_x = 0, ul_y = 1, lr_x = 1, lr_y = 0):
    # Called if you say: my_rectancle = Rectangle (-10, 10, 10, -10)
    # Puts parameters in fields of your newly created object of class Rectancle
    self.ul_x = ul_x
    self.ul_y = ul_y
    self.lr_x = lr_x
    self.lr_y = lr_y

  # compute cirumference
  def circumference (self):
    return 2 * (self.ur_x - self.lr_x) + 2 * (self.ul_y - self.lr_y)

  # compute area
  def area (self):
    return (self.ur_x - self.lr_x) * (self.ul_y - self.lr_y)
```

[EDIT]

With regard to the additional code in your comment, it's quite close to what it should be. With some corrections:

```
# determine length of Rectangle
def length (self):
    return self.ul_y - self.lr_y

# determine width of Rectangle
def width (self):
    return self.lr_x - self.ul_x
    # self. has been added, since e.g. lr_x is not a parameter
    # of the width function, but a field of the object you make
    # by instantiation: 'rectangle = Rectangle (10, 20, 100, 200)'
    # After that, self refers to the object 'rectangle' you created,
    # which has class 'Rectangle'.
    #
    # Note that a class is a type.
    # You can have a type 'Dog'.
    # Dog 'fluffy' is an instance of that class, so a particular dog.
    # In the methods (functions) of 'Dog', 'self' refers to the particular
    # dog you're working with.

# determine the perimeter
def perimeter (self):
    return 2 * self.width () + 2 * self.length ()
    # Note the () after width and length.
    # They're needed because width and length are
    # function calls (they DO something) rather than fields (data)
    # You could also have stored width and length into fields,
    # just like the constructor did with ul_x, ul_y, lr_x and lr_y,
    # storing them in self.ul_x, self.ul_y etc.
    # Then the braces wouldn't have been needed.

    # But also out some superfluous braces here
    # Multiplication goes before addition anyhow
    # And return returns everything after it, no braces needed.       

# determine the area
def area (self):
    return self.width () * self.length ()
```

So, how far did you get now?

Comment: ' # determine length of Rectangle
  def length (self):
    return (ul_y - lr_y)

  # determine width of Rectangle
  def width (self):
    return (lr_x - ul_x)

  # determine the perimeter
  def perimeter (self):
    return ((2* self.width) + (2 * self.length))
    
  # determine the area
  def area (self):
    return (self.width * self.length)'